# Flash Auto Pause video after x seconds and play after selected option

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, actionscript, adobe

I am doing project on developing a small game(A Soccer Penalty shootout guess game). I was hoping if someone could tell if it is possible to do the following function. I am using Adobe Flash Pro CC.

I am trying to pause the video that i have imported at 3.5 seconds and then two buttons appear with options either a Miss or Goal.. Once the user selects either option the video continues to play.

My question, is it possible to do this using Actionscript in Flash. if so what commands/function does it require.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is indeed possible... now please give more details about the video's class.

Comment: I am new to flash... What are the video class??

Comment: How are you streaming the video?

Comment: the video is embedded in the flash... Source file from computer

Comment: So it is a component class?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like this (given that you are using the FLVPlayback component with the variable name of `myFLVPlaybackComponent`)

should be

```
myFLVPlaybackComponent.addEventListener(VideoEvent.PLAYHEAD_UPDATE, videoPause);

private function videoPause(evt:VideoEvent):void {
    if (evt.playheadTime >= 3500){
    myFLVPlaybackComponent.stop();
   }
}
```

then call `myFLVPlaybackComponent.play();` on your resume video function